# Dash - Run callback in server side

Tags: callback, scheduled-tasks, plotly-dash

Good morning,

I have created a callback in Dash that makes the job of a scheduler.
Every 10 minutes (with the help of an interval component), my callback is running to fetch the data from a server and to update the csv file that I use in my app.

The problem is that my callback is called only when I have the webpage opened. As soon as I close the page, the scheduler stops and runs again when I open the page again.

As the data process of updating data can be long sometimes, I want the scheduler to always run and fetch the data every 10 minutes.

I assume that a callback is a client side process right? So how can I make it run in server side?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Dash is probably not the right solution for this. I think it would make more sense to set up the Python code you need for this job in a simple `.py` script file, and set a cron job to run that script every 10 min.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not sure to understand the solution you propose. How the scheduler script that I will write and execute outside of my dash app will "talk" with the dash app?

Comment: I don't think it would need to. If you're just reading a CSV file, the scheduled script could handle updating that file, and your Dash app would still read from it. A true database, rather than a file, is probably the best way, but this could still work.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tested Cron in a docker and it's not working as I wanted to. It seems I have to wait 1-2 minutes before the script is executing for the first time. 
Ideally, I would like my container which is fetching the data and nourrish the csv to run itself every 10 minutes but I don't know if there is a way. 
Do you think a simple script in container A with a while loop + a commande to run container B + a sleep is something acceptable for that?

Comment: That sounds like it could work

Comment: That's what I did finally and it's working great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @coralvanda for the help.

I finally did a python script in my container A that calls the container B every 10 minutes. The container B is fetching the data.

It makes the job.

```
import schedule
import time
import docker

def worker_restart():
    client = docker.from_env()
    container = client.containers.get('container_worker')
    container.restart()

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(worker_restart)
while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```